# error in Angular js Services TDD

Tags: angularjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

new to Angular TDD, and am getting an error, which I am unable to debug, any insights will be helpful

I have a services file

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('usersLocationService', function () {
    this.SetLocation = function (place) {
        var address = {};
        //some code
        return address;
   };
 });
```

my karma.conf.js has this

```
files: [      
    'test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular.min.js',
    'test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular-mocks.js',
    'public/Services/*.js',
    'test/unitTest/spec/client/**/*.js'
],
```

My test file is

```
"use strict";
describe('Test Suite for UserLocationService', function () {
var usersLocationService, httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, _usersLocationService_) {
    module('myApp');
    usersLocationService = _usersLocationService_;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
}));


it('Should return the address from the google location place', function () {
    var place = {};
    var data = this.usersLocationService.SetLocation(place);
    console.log(place);
});
});
```

The error that I am getting is

Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
  at C:/project/test/unitTest/spec/client/lib/angular.min.js:6

This error is coming up in the main Services file and not in the specFile, To confirm, I changed the value in the service file to myServices and the angular error came up as nomod?p0=myServices. Am I missing out in any libraries that need to be added?

Comment: try remove `` and add `beforeEach(module('myApp'));` before `beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, _usersLocationService_`

Comment: I did try that before, beforeEach(module('myApp')); before the beforeEach(inject). Did not work. What is the remove``?

Comment: Did you remove module('myApp'); when you try?

Comment: yes, my Spec Code looks like this  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    var usersLocationService, httpBackend;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend, _usersLocationService_) {
        usersLocationService = _usersLocationService_;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));

Comment: This error is happening during the angular.module('myApp') in my main js file. Is it not finding angular.min.js file while loading the service?

Answer (score 0):

in my services file when I wrote the code as below it worked fine

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
```